# sqlalchemy update not commiting changes to database. Using single connection in an app

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy in a pyqt desktop application. When I execute and update to the database the changes are not reflected in the database, if I inspect the session object 'sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.ScopedSession', it tell's me that my object is not present in the session, but if I try to added It tells me that is already present.
The way I'm managing the connections is the following, when the application starts I open a connection and keep it open all the user session, when the application is closed I close the connection. Thus all queries are performed opening only one connection.

```
selected_mine = Mine.query.filter_by(mine_name="some_name").first()
''' updating the object attributes '''
selected_mine.region = self.ui.region.text() 
self.sqlite_model.conn.commit()
```

I've inspect the sessions, and there are two different objects (I don't know why).

```
s=self.sqlite_model.conn()
>>> s
<sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0x30fb210>
s.object_session(selected_mine)
>>> <sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0x30547d0>
```

how do I solve this? why the commit it's not working?

I'm creating the session in the class SqliteModel (class of the object self.sqlite_model)

```
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, bind=self.engine))
self.conn = Session()

Base.query = Session.query_property()        

''' connect to database '''
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=self.engine)
```

Comment: How are you creating the first `session` object?

Answer (score 1):

You don't show what the `Mine` class is, but I believe your issue lies with this line:

```
selected_mine = Mine.query.filter_by(mine_name="some_name").first()
```

You are not actually using the session that you originally setup to query the database thus a new session is being created for you. I believe your code should look like this instead:

```
selected_mine = self.conn.query(Mine).filter_by(mine_name="some_name").first()
```

If you haven't done so yet, you should definitely glance through the [excellent documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html) that SQLAlchemy has made available explaining what a `Session` is and how to use it.